# Convert a method with nested subscribes to an RxJS pipe

Tags: rxjs

I have a code pattern that looks (simplified) like this:

```
loadDocs(): DocType {
    this.http.get('/doc/1').subscribe(
      (doc1) => {
        this.http.get('/doc/' + '(something based on doc1)').subscribe(
          (doc2) => {
              return doc2;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

What I want to do is convert that to a function that returns an Observable like:

```
loadDocs(): Observable<TypeDoc> {
    return this.http.get('/doc/1').pipe(
       // ???
    );
}
```

I am sure this is very basic but so far I haven't been able to find an example of which RxJS
operators to use in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking for `switchMap` in this case:

```
loadDocs(): Observable<TypeDoc> {
    return this.http.get('/doc/1').pipe(
       switchMap(doc1 => this.http.get('/doc/' + '(something based on doc1)'))
    );
}
```

`mergeMap` and `concatMap` would work the same here since http calls are single emission observables, the differences between them are only apparent with observables that emit multiple times. IMO `switchMap` is semantically most correct with http calls as it implies there will only be one active inner subscription, but opinions on this will vary.

They're all higher order operators that take the current value and map it into a new inner observable that they subscribe to and return the value